# Default timeout and keep-alive settings for memorystore

Tags: timeout, settings, keep-alive, google-cloud-memorystore

We're planning a migration from our own hosted redis instances to Google Cloud Memorystore. But there seems to be one thing I cannot find any answers to in the documentation:

- default memorystore timeout settings
- default tcp keep-alive settings

We have some connection bleeding in one part of the app (due to pre-emptible nodes and oom crashes in Kubernetes) and need to make sure these are set to *some* sane value.

They are not under "Modifiable": https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/reference/redis-configs#modifiable_configuration_parameters

But also not listed under "Unmodifiable": https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/reference/redis-configs#unmodifiable_configuration_parameters

How can I figure out these settings (and others)? (`CONFIG` is a blocked command)

Answer (score 1):

Being Cloud Memorystore a fully-managed service you are limited to change only a very limited amount of parameters. As stated on the relevant section of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-overview#differences_between_managed_and_open_source_redis):

> Most parameters are preconfigured for Cloud Memorystore for Redis instances, and you cannot change them. Other parameters you configure when you set up your Cloud Memorystore for Redis instance. For more information, see [Redis Configuration Parameters](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/reference/redis-configs).

As of now, and as you well mention, [these](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/reference/redis-configs#modifiable_configuration_parameters) are the only modifiable parameters. And you can't modify the `timeout` nor the `tcp-keepalive` parameters.

The documentation makes mention of the following [REDIS.CONF](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/4.0/redis.conf) file in which the default values are:

```
timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 300
```